# Excel return multiple unique values from matching criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'v a table with data like this:

COLA  COLB

PEAD  SDR1

PEAD  SDR1

PEAD  SDR2

PEAD  SDR2

PEAD  SDR3

PVC   PN10

PVC   PN10

PVC   PN12,5

PVC   PN16

And a table that i want to get the info on like this:
COLA COLB

Type Pressure

PEAD

If i select the Type to PEAD i want the Pressure cell to have a dropdown with SDR1, SDR2, SDR3 (each one only showing once!),if the type is PVC i want the dropdown to show PN10, PN12,5, PN16.

Thank you

Comment: Is the data in two columns? COLA, PEAD, PEAD, etc. in the first? And COLB, SDR1, SDR1. etc. in the second? And then, more importantly, is the dynamic drop down list going to ONLY be in one cell such as A10?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `If()` and Data Validation.  Say you want the drop down to be in cell A10.  Select A10, then go to Data Tab --> Data Validation.  Choose "List" from the "Allow" dropbox, then in the formula area, you can type `=If(A9="PEAD",B1:B9,C1:C9)`.

It assumes that B1:B9 contains your unique values to show if the Type is "PEAD".  C1:C9 is for unique values for "PVC".  Adjust as necessary.

Is that the sort of thing you're looking for?

Comment: I'v more options... PEX, etc... I dont want to hand pick every option, i want it more dynamic, ur suggestion mean i will have a bunch of "if" clauses for each type. I guess i must split the table between two, to avoid duplicate values, and it might get easier to use index-match formula to try and place it as dropdown. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: @JoãoSilva - I was going to suggest that, try using Index/Match (or maybe a vlookup?) when doing the statement.